# Constraining Javascript canvas shapes to a specified area

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Is there a way to constrain text, rectangles, and other shapes/elements to a specified rectangle in javascript? I am building a tool for use in another project and I want to draw a smaller window with text inside, and have this window overlay everything else. However, I also want the text (and any other elements inside) to not be able to flow outside of the window.

I have tried to draw this interior window and the elements inside first so as to overlay all other elements over it, but this doesn't work because other elements obscure the items inside the smaller window, instead of just covering up the sections outside. Is there a built-in way to do this? Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an imitation of the window on the canvas, you need to implement "polygon clipping", everything that will be inside the window will be displayed, and what will go beyond its boundary will be cut off.

You'll need the **clip()** method

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

// Set the clipping rectangle
const windowX = 50;
const windowY = 50;
const windowWidth = 100;
const windowHeight = 200;

// before clippings
ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
ctx.strokeRect(windowX, windowY, windowWidth, windowHeight);

// Create a rectangle path
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(windowX, windowY, windowWidth, windowHeight);

// Clip the canvas to the specified rectangle
ctx.clip();
ctx.closePath();

// Draw on the clipped area
// Example: draw a circle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(150, 150, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I remove the clip after drawing the window?

Comment: I guess you have to use the save() and restore() methods